# How deserialize bson with json4s?

Tags: json, scala, jackson, bson, json4s

[Json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) has no examples about bson processing. Any ideas?

It also has examples with jackson, but I do not undestand how to configure jackson like [that](http://www.michel-kraemer.com/binary-json-with-bson4jackson) under json4s to read from binary bson input. Does somebody know?

Comment: why do you think it is possible in the first place? While BSON is similar to JSON, it has a different, larger set of types which does not map exactly to json4s JSON AST.

Comment: Nor very familiar with AST, but If you look at jackson there is bson4jackson module so there can be a hack (**theoretically**) to use it in json4s.

Comment: Jackson is not really related here. It has an XML parser as well, but it does not mean that json4s will be able to use jackson to deserialize its AST from XML. If json4s does not support it explicitly, I don't think you will be able to do it without writing glue code first, and only for JSON AST -> BSON AST conversion. That is, I think you can do something like json4s already does with XML, but I doubt you can do more than that, including direct serialization from case classes to BSON, for example.